# Getting deceptive/malware content sites list with Google Safe Browsing v4

Tags: php, api

First of all I am not a programmer. I am starting small project to kill time. I am using Google Safe Browsing API v4 in PHP to get the deceptive sites which contain malware. I searched on Google and was able to get what I want. But if I turn on error reporting, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$matches in /var/www/html/working.php on line 55
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/working.php on line 55

The cause of the error is because, if a site is not listed as a deceptive site, then it will respond with an empty JSON. Due to this, the following line will not execute and will throw that error:

```
$stats=$str->matches[0]->threatType;
```

This PHP script will read the **sites.txt** file which contains website names per line and lists sites according to Google Safe Browsing. I want to handle this error. Please review this script and suggest ways to minimize the script, execution time, etc.

```
<html>
<head>
        <style>
                *{padding: 0; margin: 0}
                #wrap{ padding: 0 10px; width: 620px }
                .left{float: left; width: 305px}
                .right{float: right; width: 305px}
                .warning{background: red;color: white; padding: 0 5px}
                .ok{background: green;color: white; padding: 0 5px}
                .clear{clear: both}
        </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sites = fopen("sites.txt", "r");
$apikey = "GOOGLE-API-KEY";
$url_api ="https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=".$apikey."";

function GETData($url, $post){
 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post)));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $result=curl_exec($ch);
 return $result;
}
echo '<div id="wrap">';
if($sites){
        while (($line = fgets($sites)) !== false){
                $data=
                '{
                  "client": {
                  "clientId": "TestClient",
                  "clientVersion": "1.0"
                  },
                  "threatInfo": {
                  "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
                  "platformTypes":    ["LINUX"],
                  "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
                  "threatEntries": [
                   {"url": "'.$line.'"}
    ]
  }
}';

$GOtest=GETData($url_api, $data);
$str=json_decode($GOtest);
$stats=$str->matches[0]->threatType;

if(isset($stats)){
        echo '<div class="left">' . $line . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="right">';
        echo '<span class="warning">' . $stats . "<br>" . '</span></div>';
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
else{
        echo '<div class="left">' . $line . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="right">'; 
        echo '<span class="ok">' . "Looks OK". "<br>" . '</span></div>';
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
}
fclose($sites);
 echo '</div>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: [Notice:  Undefined property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10143172/6660678)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Heredoc

> ```
>                 $data=
>                 '{
>                   "client": {
>                   "clientId": "TestClient",
>                   "clientVersion": "1.0"
>                   },
>                   "threatInfo": {
>                   "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
>                   "platformTypes":    ["LINUX"],
>                   "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
>                   "threatEntries": [
>                    {"url": "'.$line.'"}
>     ]
>   }
> }';
> ```

It's more common to use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and string interpolation for a multiline string like this.

```
                $data = <<<EOJSON
{
    "client": {
     "clientId": "TestClient",
     "clientVersion": "1.0"
    },
    "threatInfo": {
     "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
     "platformTypes":    ["LINUX"],
     "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
     "threatEntries":    [
      {"url": "$line"}
     ]
  }
}
EOJSON;
```

#### Simplifying

> ```
> $stats=$str->matches[0]->threatType;
>
> if(isset($stats)){
>         echo '<div class="left">' . $line . '</div>';
>         echo '<div class="right">';
>         echo '<span class="warning">' . $stats . "<br>" . '</span></div>';
>         echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
> }
> else{
>         echo '<div class="left">' . $line . '</div>';
>         echo '<div class="right">'; 
>         echo '<span class="ok">' . "Looks OK". "<br>" . '</span></div>';
>         echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
> }
> ```

You can rewrite this

```
    echo '<div class="left">' . $line . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="right">';
    if (property_exists($str, 'matches')) {
        echo '<span class="warning">' . $str->matches[0]->threatType . '<br></span></div>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<span class="ok">Looks OK<br></span></div>';
    }
    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
```

This saves repeating three lines that are identical.  Only the one line that changes is inside the `if`.

I also compressed the strings.  PHP doesn't automatically merge string literals, so this might make some small performance difference.

Comment: looks good except this line where you have mentioned three closing brackets instead of two `if (property_exists($str, 'matches'))) {`.  I am still looking for other ideas.

Comment: I think it is what I want. It, atleast minimizes my code. Accepting this as my answer. Thanks again.